# Using variable to calculate field with ArcPy as script in toolbox?

Tags: arcpy

```
stringvariable = "banana"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("c:\point.shp", "SUBDIRECT", "stringvariable", "PYTHON")
```

I get an error saying stringvariable is not defined what's the deal? I check stringvariable by printing it to screen and it contains what it should. I am trying to use a string variable to calculate a field with arcpy. I am stumped. Also it works like this when run as a script through idle or outside of arcmap, but now I am trying to add this script to a toolbox and I am getting this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should be:

```
stringvariable = "banana"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("c:\point.shp", "SUBDIRECT", "'" + stringvariable + "'", "PYTHON")
```

If you double quote stringvariable, Python won't interpret it as "banana". Also, You have to quote the string for the field calculator to work.

Comment: thank you. i found the answer and this was part of it the other part was that my variable contained slashes and underscores so I used: import re, stringvariable = re.escape(stringvariable) to translate it to string literal.